# How to decide the number of significant figures?

Tags: conventions, measurements, error-analysis

When we do calculations involving [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) with their uncertainties, Which rule/rules do we use to decide the number of significant figures in the result?

Comment: More on [significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+significant+figures).

Answer (score 1):

As a good rule of thumb, the *least* number of significant figures in any *input* determines the number of significant figures in the output.

Comment: G. Smith. If the numbers don't have uncertainties we can just use that rule. But there is also a rule that fractional percentage uncertainties determine the number of significant figures allowed?

Comment: All measured inputs have uncertainties.

Comment: Yes. Let say we measure the length and width of a table. We include uncertainties in the results of measurement. Then we want to find its area by multiplying them. After we multiply these two numbers, there is a rule to follow the least number of significant figures. But then when we calculate the percentage of fractional uncertainty, we also have a rule to follow based on the value of the percentage of fractional uncertainty. Do we use both rules?

Comment: I consider counting the number of significant digits to be a simple order-of-magnitude approximation to calculating the fractional uncertainty. If you have, say, three significant digits, the fractional uncertainty is going to be between 0.01 (if the digits are 100) and 0.001 (if the digits are 999).